# How to remove item from adapter

Tags: android, view, null, adapter

I have a container, adapter, and couple items. I would like to save items into database one by one.
However, I have issue on getting next item from adapter and resize adapter.
So far I have the code below:

```
adapter.add(item[0]);
adapter.add(item[1]);
adapter.add(item[2]);

item = adaper.getItem(0);

item.setDismissListener(new Item.OnDimissedListener(){
    @Override
    public void save(){
        1. save item to database, it works here

        2. get next item, I do
           item = adapter.removeFirst(); // this one returns null pointer exception.
    }
}

container.setAdapter(adapter);   // set adapter here
```

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Is the `adapter` object not `null` when you call `adapter.removeFirst()`?

Comment: If I simply call item = adapter,removeFirst() outside of setDismissListener. It's not null. But I can't tell if the inside statement will return null because I got null pointer exeception from it.

Comment: Have you declared `adapter` as an field of the outer class?

Comment: No. I declare it in the same class

Comment: @user3594418 Can you show the log of your error? (if it's crashing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar project where I stored strings in a SQLite database and users could add/delete/modify items. What I did was to temporarily store the list of items in an `ArrayList<String>` and then update the ListView adapter with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` when that `ArrayList` changes.

In your case, I'd try something like this:

```
// Create an ArrayList <String>
    ArrayList<String> itemsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemsArray.add( YOUR_ITEMS_GO_HERE );
    ...

// add data in ArrayAdapter
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, itemsArray);
    ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

// Perform your Save actions

// Delete the first item in the ArrayList
   list.remove(0); // removes the first item

// Update the ListView
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you are not using Strings, replace `<String>` with your `<Object Type>`